# How to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac4{n^2}\right)^n$?

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

> How to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac4{n^2}\right)^n$?

---

I know that $e = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+ \dfrac1n\right)^n$ may be useful. But I don't know how this could be used here.

Comment: I see! thank you all !!!

Answer (score 2):

Note that$$\left(1+\frac4{n^2}\right)^n=\left(\left(1+\frac4{n^2}\right)^{n^2}\right)^{1/n}.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: I have to say that the $n$ on the radical is next to impossible to see, at least in my browser. Maybe reformat it?

Comment: @peterag Is it better now?

Comment: Thanks - clearer

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite
$$ \left(1+\frac{4}{n^2} \right)^n = \left(1+\frac{4}{n^2} \right)^{\large\frac{n^2}{4}\frac{4}{n}}$$
which goes to $e^0 = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use the fact that

$$\lim_\infty \left(1+\frac {4}{n^2}\right)^{n^2}=e^4 $$

Answer (score 1):

$$(1+4/(n^2))^n =\exp\left(\frac{4}{n}\frac{\ln(1+ \frac{4}{n^2})}{\frac{4}{n^2}}\right) \to1$$

since $$\frac{\ln(1+ h)}{h}\to 1~~as~~~ h\to0$$